# Nest compatibility with Node.js

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I just installed Nest CLI with the following command, while using Node v14:

```
npm install -g @nestjs/cli
```

Then I switched Node version using `nvm` and the command `nest` is no longer recognizable.

- Node v18.16 -  Works
- Node v18.17.1 - Doesn't work
- Node v20 - Doesn't work

Error:

```
✗ nvm use 20    
Now using node v20.5.1 (npm v9.8.0)

✗ nest      
zsh: command not found: nest
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide), Nest v10 should work with Node v16 or higher.
Any idea why this stops working with any version higher than 18.16?

Comment: You can't conclude from that that it doesn't work in those versions, just that you haven't installed it for them. NVM installations are separate, they don't share global modules.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the information. So the `Global` isn't all global?  
Also, if that is the case, why it works on `V18.16` if I installed while using `V14`? Not sayin that isn't the answer, just want to understand.

Comment: Global means "not just for this package", not "for every Node version on your computer". You can explore what each one has with e.g. `npm --location=global ls`. Are any of those versions your system installation? Might you have previously installed the Nest CLI for any? Probably the easiest thing to do is _not_ use global installs as far as possible, and trigger CLI commands via package scripts instead.

Answer (score 0):

Different `nvm` version installations don't share globally installed packages by default. You have installed the package for Node 14. You probably at some point also installed it for Node 18.

`nvm` provides the option to migrate global packages when installing a new node version: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#migrating-global-packages-while-installing